# Why does this for loop code work with a condition that isn't accepted?

Tags: c++

I can't understand why this code working. Variable `a` is given number by user, and according test with debug `i=a` is not accepted as condition, but `i` just takes a number of `a`, after then a given number, let`s say 3333, is divided by 10 until it becomes 0. When a = 0, program just finishes.

If i = a wasn`t accepted as condition why does program stop when (a) reach 0? I checked this code on CLion,Dev C++ and Online Compiler.

```
double DigitCountSum(int a)
{
    int s = 0, n;
    for (int i = 1; i = a; i++) {
        n = a % 10;
        s += n;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << DigitCountSum(a) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have `i=a` as condition, and as `a` is 0, `i` will be assigned 0 and the expression will also result in 0, which will be considered false and thus break the loop. You probably meant to write `i==a` instead.

Comment: You should also explain exactly what it is that surprises you.

Comment: @SWdV this can now be posted as an answer, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

```
for (int i = 1; i = a; i++)
```

`i = a` is assignment, not comparison. You should use `==` for comparison. However, even if you change this to `==`, the logic still won't be correct (because then the loop would iterate once in the special case that `a = 1` and 0 times otherwise).

Did you mean to write `i <= a`?

Incidentally, I think that a `while` loop could be a better choice here - comparing `i` to `a` doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Also, you're currently not doing anything with `s` or `n`, so those parts of the code are not currently needed.

Also, `double` really doesn't make sense as a return type because the answer can only be an integer. After all, a number can't have 2.3 digits, for example.